# How to Set JPanel's Width and Height?

Tags: java, swing, fixed-width

I'm developing Snake game using Java. Board's (where all action takes it place) width and height should be fixed (640 pixels * 480 pixels).

Structure:

- *Main class* that extends from *JFrame* class,
- *Board* class that extends from *JPanel* class;

In *Main* class I have something like...

```
setSize( 1024, 768 );
```

...and in Board class I have...

```
setSize( BOARDS_WIDTH, BOARDS_HEIGHT );
```

Problem is that main and only windows seems to be like 1024 * 768, but panel inside it - not like 640 * 480. I have *setBackground()* as well and background is filled more than 640 * 480.

Is there any way to make Board's width and height like 640 * 480, but main windows width and height - as much as Board's width and height are correct?

Right now it looks like this...

[image: Width and height are ~1000 * ~750, not 640 * 480.]

**Edit:**

All works... almost.

*Main* class:

```
add( new Board(), BorderLayout.CENTER );
pack();
setResizable( false );
setLocationRelativeTo( null );
setVisible( true );
setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
setTitle( "Snake (by daGrevis)" );
```

*Board* class:

```
setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 640, 480 ) );
```

Gray background is 642 * 482! Like there would be border that wraps all by 1 pixel!

Comment: It is generally not necessary to extend components unless adding additional functionality (e.g. new methods).

Comment: Will keep it in my mind. I'm just newbie in Java!

Comment: For help beyond what has already been offered (by someone who I regard as one of the 'Gurus of Swing'), I suggest you post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

please, something went x*x*x*x, and that's not true at all, check that

```
JButton Size - java.awt.Dimension[width=400,height=40]
JPanel Size - java.awt.Dimension[width=640,height=480]
JFrame Size - java.awt.Dimension[width=646,height=505]
```

code (basic stuff from [Trail: Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) , and yet I still satisfied that that would be outdated )

EDIT: forget `setDefaultCloseOperation()`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FrameSize {

    private JFrame frm = new JFrame();
    private JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
    private JButton btn = new JButton("Get ScreenSize for JComponents");

    public FrameSize() {
        btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 40));
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("JButton Size - " + btn.getSize());
                System.out.println("JPanel Size - " + pnl.getSize());
                System.out.println("JFrame Size - " + frm.getSize());
            }
        });
        pnl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        pnl.add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frm.add(pnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frm.setLocation(150, 100);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // EDIT
        frm.setResizable(false);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                FrameSize fS = new FrameSize();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The "big problem" was that I needed to call setResizable( false ) false before add()!

Answer (score 9):

```
board.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x, y));
.
.
//main.add(Board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
main.add(Board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
main.setLocations(x, y);
main.pack();
main.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Yup, +1, but I've not used setLocations -- perhaps the s is a typo. I also sometimes call setLocationRelativeTo(null) after calling pack to center the GUI.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. Just 'Borderlayout' should be 'BorderLayout'.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels < :-) > hmmm, just.., I hate :-) `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` and `setLocationByPlatform(true)`</:-)>

Comment: I have little problem, guys. Can't accept this answer! =D Please look at my question's edits.

Comment: @mKorbel:  "I hate :-) setLocationRelativeTo(null) and setLocationByPlatform(true)</:-)"  *Why?*  (I use both methods frequently!)

Comment: -1 the answer should promote proper Java naming conventions. Variable names should not start with an upper cased character.

Comment: so somehow (unconsciously) I want to have that in the upper left corner and not look for it on the screen (2 pcs) and do not feel like `GraphicEnviroment[]` too,

Comment: @ camickr  +1 for correct advice, but it has been deliberately, I just follows @daGrevis's ClassNames

Comment: Isn't that correct that all variables are camelCased, constants are LIKE_THIS, but class' names are like CamelCasedWithFirstLatterStillCapitalized?