# How can I resize the height of a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, size, layout-manager

```
//Attributes
//Stats GUI components
JLabel hp = new JLabel();
JLabel hpPoints = new JLabel("TEST");
JLabel chakra = new JLabel();
JLabel chakraPoints = new JLabel("TEST");
JLabel ryo = new JLabel();
JLabel ryoPoints = new JLabel("TEST");

//Output & Input GUI components
JTextField input = new JTextField();
JTextArea output = new JTextArea(1000, 300);
JPanel statsPanel = new JPanel(); 
JPanel outputPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();

//Constructor
public Terminal() {
    
    setTitle("Shinobi Shinso");
    setSize(1000, 600);
    //setResizable(false);
    setLocation(400, 100);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container panneau = getContentPane();
    panneau.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    statsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
    
    //Output & input
    //Add outputPanel to the panneau
    panneau.add(outputPanel);
    //Add output to outputPanel
    outputPanel.add(output);
    //Add input to outputPanel
    outputPanel.add(input);
    input.setColumns(98);
    output.setRows(15);
    output.setEditable(false);
    output.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    output.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    //Add stats panel
    panneau.add(statsPanel);
    //Statistics
    //Health
    hp.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("D:\\eclipse-workspace\\Shinobi Shinso\\images\\scroll-hp.png").getImage().
            getScaledInstance(300, 150, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
    hp.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    statsPanel.add(hp);
    hpPoints.setBounds(100, 25, 100, 100);
    hp.add(hpPoints);

    setVisible(true);
}
```

Here's how it appears :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ9UZ.png]

I tried to use a JScrollPanel and a lot of obscure coding witchcraft to no avail. I can't seem to find a way to reduce the height of the JPanel containing the pictures.

I deleted 2 of the scrolls in the picture, but I don't think that it will change anything.

Comment: Try checking this related topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921175/how-to-set-jpanels-width-and-height Hope it helps.

Comment: 1) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the intended layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width X height - to show how the extra space should be used. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) One way to get image(s) for an example is 2 hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). E.G. The code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't seem to find a way to reduce the height of the JPanel containing the pictures.

Don't use a GridLayout as the parent layout manager. The GridLayout makes all components the same size.

I would suggest you don't change the layout manager of the content pane. Leave it as the default BorderLayout.

Then use:

```
panneau.add(outputPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
panneau.add(statsPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

Also, your creation of the JTextArea is incorrect:

```
JTextArea output = new JTextArea(1000, 300);
```

The parameters are for rows/columns, not width/height.

So you should use something like:

```
JTextArea output = new JTextArea(15, 40);
```

and a text area is usually added to a JScrollPane so scrollbars can appear when needed.

Read the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics. There are section on:

1. Layout managers
2. How to Use Text Areas

that should help.